# In PHP how can I detect when a user is deleting text from an input text field

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements, formfield

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="" />
<form>
```

If there is something written in the input text field and the user start to delete the string meaning the last letter of the string I want to do something.

So something like this:

```
if(user deletes last letter of isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){
//do something
}
```

I tried to use strlen() with -1 but did not seem to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"`, you'd rather leave this attribute blank if you want the action of the form to be the page itself.

Comment: so blank by default sends the form data to the same file that the forms on?

Comment: Yes. Also, you should use javascript/jQuery to attach events on DOM-manipulation, if this what you want.

Comment: I figured javascript would be on the only way just thought it could be done with php some how. Thanks appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use javascript to do something when user is deleting char. 
One way is to listen to 'keyup' event of the text input. E.g.:

```
<script>
$(":text[name=phonenumber]").on('keyup', function(event){
   if (event.keyCode == 8){ // means BACKSPACE pressed
        // do something
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: if I may ask something about this code, the way you select the input field `$(":text[name=phonenumber]")` what does the : mean. Iv seen elements being selected through JQuery many ways but can you explain why you chose this way of selecting the phonenumber field

Comment: @LucasSantos <code>':text'</code> is to select<code><input type=text></code>. See http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/ .

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by using javascript. on every keyup you have to count the textbox value by id if it is decreasing from the max count means user is deleting some text..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @Clarence had the rite idea

Answer (score 0):

you should use javascript with event keyup ,

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('input[name=phonenumber]').on('keyup', function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 46)
       {
          $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url : 'url',
             data :{'phonenumber': $('input[name=phonenumber]').val()},});
       }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the reply appreciate it. Although I went with @Clarence code because it's simplified and it works. Thanks again

Comment: I just add $.ajax() to send value of  "phonenumber" because you can't get the last value of input without this function . Good luck !